# full calendar_scheduler - How to set min-width Resource columns in vertical agenda day and have a horizontal scroll

Tags: css, plugins

**Hello every one, I have an issue, please help me !**
I use Scheduler in FullCalendar. When I added more resources, the columns of resource is smaller to fix the calendar. I want to set min-width of column and show a horizontal scroll. I tried to set

> .fc-view.fc-agendaDay-view.fc-agenda-view{ width: 500%; }

but it inefficient. Because when I add more resource, the columns will smaller again.

Comment: Do you have any related Javascript or HTML that you could post? This will help us to better visualize your problem and solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I use fullcalendar.io  so the HTML is `<div id="calendar"></div>`
and JS to show more resource column is

> resources: [
>  { id: 'BSNa', title: 'Bác sĩ Na'}
>   { id: 'BSHai', title: 'Bác sĩ Hải' },
>   { id: 'BSPhuong', title: 'Bác sĩ Phương' },
>    { id: 'BSAnh', title: 'Bác sĩ Ánh'},
>   { id: 'BSMinh', title: 'Bác sĩ Minh'},
>                       { id: 'KTVa', title: 'KTV Ánh',  },
>                       { id: 'KTVb', title: 'KTV Minh',  },
>                       { id: 'KTVc', title: 'KTV Ánh',  },
>                       { id: 'KTVd', title: 'KTV Minh', },
>   ]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWy5L.png)